# How to test AWS Lambda Docker image locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

So I created this docker image `etl-pipeline` and I want to test if it works. My Dockerfile looks like this.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.4.0

RUN pip install "poetry==$POETRY_VERSION"

WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create true && poetry install --only main --no-interaction --no-ansi


COPY app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/
COPY scraper_backend ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/scraper_backend

CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

So to build the Dockerfile I used `docker build -t etl-pipeline .`
and I wanted to run it by running the command `docker run etl-pipeline`

But nothing happens. My output looks like this.

```
$ docker run etl_pipeline
13 Apr 2023 14:05:36,800 [INFO] (rapid) exec '/var/runtime/bootstrap' (cwd=/var/task, handler=)
```

and then it just keeps on running. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's sitting there running, waiting on you to send requests to it. I suggest reading the official documentation on testing AWS Lambda container images https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-test.html

Answer (score -1):

The container is running and the command is waiting for it to finish.

If you want that the `docker run` command will exit while the container keeps running in the background, you should use the `-d` flag for detached mode:

```
docker run -d etl-pipeline
```